# Kraus representation for maps between trace-class operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

[image]

This is the Kraus Theorem. But, the map $\mathcal{M}$ is the dual map of a map $\Phi : \mathfrak{T}(\mathcal{H}) \to \mathfrak{T}(\mathcal{H})$ where $\mathfrak{T}(\mathcal{H})$ is the banach space of trace-class operators. Then from the theorem above, is it possible to obtain an expression analogous to (6.14) for $\Phi$? I am very despeate and curious... Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Phi$ be a linear and completely positive map on $\frak T(\mathcal H)$ where $\mathcal H$ is a separable Hilbert space. Then its dual map $\Phi^*$ acting on $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ is linear and completely positive *(the equivalence of complete positivity of $\Phi$ and $\Phi^*$ is well known)* and the duality relation implies that $\Phi^*$ is ultraweakly *(here: $\sigma$-weakly)* continous. Now we can apply Theorem 6.23 to $\Phi^*$ to get

$$
\operatorname{tr}(\Phi(A)B)=\operatorname{tr}(A\Phi^*(B))\overset{(6.14)}=\operatorname{tr}\Big(A\sum_n M_n^*BM_n\Big)=\sum_n\operatorname{tr}(AM_n^*BM_n)\\=\sum_n\operatorname{tr}(M_nAM_n^*B)=\operatorname{tr}\Big(\sum_n M_nAM_n^*B\Big)
$$

for all $A\in\frak T(\mathcal H), B\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ using that the trace is linear, continous and cyclic. Thus every such $\Phi$ has a representation

$$
\Phi(A)=\sum_n M_nAM_n^*\tag{1}
$$

for all $A\in\frak T(\mathcal H)$ where $\sum_n M_n^*M_n$ converges strongly and (1) even converges with respect to the trace norm *(by Proposition 6.3 of [that Attal chapter](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~attal/Quantum_Channels.pdf) you quoted in your question)*.

Comment: Could you please specify the convergence of (1) in your answer? Also, is it possible to get (1) from the above equation? How the equality for the trace values ensure the equality of two maps?

Comment: In my answer it already says that (1) is trace-norm convergent (I even gave a source to that). Also I edited my answer for you to see where I used (6.14). For the equality of the two traces. Assume $\operatorname{tr}(T_1S)=\operatorname{tr}(T_2S)$ for all $S\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$, then in particular this holds for $S=\langle x,\cdot\rangle y$ with arbitrary $x,y\in\mathcal H$. Therefore $\langle x,T_1y\rangle=\langle x,T_2y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\mathcal H$ $\Rightarrow$ $T_1y=T_2y$ for all $y\in\mathcal H$ $\Rightarrow$ $T_1=T_2$.

Comment: $\langle x,\cdot\rangle y$ is just a shorthand notation for the bounded linear map $S_{x,y}:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H$, $z\mapsto \langle x,z\rangle y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. One last question : how to derive $<x, T_1y>$ from $tr(T_1S)$?

Comment: Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be any orthonormal basis of $\mathcal H$. Then $\operatorname{tr}(T_1S_{x,y})=\sum_n\langle e_n,T_1S_{x,y}e_n\rangle=\sum_n\langle e_n,T_1y\rangle\langle x,e_n\rangle=\langle x,\sum_n\langle e_n,T_1y\rangle e_n\rangle=\langle x,T_1y\rangle$ by the usual expansion $z=\sum_n \langle e_n,z\rangle e_n$.

Comment: I see... I enormously thank you.

Comment: No worries, always glad to help out! :)